# How to display error display message for few seconds - Laravel

Tags: laravel

This might be a very simple question but i can't seem to find this. How can 
make my redirect flash an error and it should also disappear after few seconds

```
 return redirect('admin/all')->with('error','Failed.');
```

I changed the status to error but i didnt do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a id where you showing your displaying your error and write a **jquery** like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#successMessage').fadeOut('fast');
}, 30000);
```

Comment: If you used this then your div will be hide after 30 sec.I also tried this one and it worked for me.